# Prove the concavity of $F(x,y) =\ln(x)+y$ by arguing the definition of concavity.

Tags: convex-analysis

I need help with this problem.

Prove the concavity of $F(x,y) = \ln(x) + y$ by arguing the definition of concavity.

A function $f$ is concave is for any $x_0, x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $t \in [0,1]$,  $$
f((1 - t) x_0 + t x_1) \geq (1 - t) f(x_0) + t f(x_1)
$$

Also, I am not allowed to use the theorem that the sum of concave functions is concave.

Comment: What is your definition of concavity?

Comment: Do you already have the result that the log function is concave?

Comment: I'm assuming it is

Comment: What do you mean by "arguing the definition"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show that for any $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ and any $t\in[0,1]$,

$$\ln\big(tx_0+(1-t)x_1\big)+ty_0+(1-t)y_1\ge t(\ln x_0+y_0)+(1-t)(\ln x_1+y_1)\;;$$

after a little simplification this becomes

$$\ln\big(tx_0+(1-t)x_1\big)\ge t\ln x_0+(1-t)\ln x_1\;.$$

If you already know that the log is concave, you’re done at this point.

Comment: What if I do not know that the log is concave, how can I prove this inequality?

Comment: @Nik: Use the second derivative.

Comment: Is there a way of proving it without using the derivative? That is another part of the question.

Comment: @Nik: I’ve not really thought about it, but I shouldn’t be at all surprised: the inequality is equivalent (after exponentiation) to $t_x_0+(1-t)x_1\ge x_0^tx_1^{1-t}$, which is a special case of the [weighted AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), whose unweighted case has many proofs.